# pytest case for main method without calling internal functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am writing pytest for my code.
I want to call the main_method() but not the functions internally. Just for code coverage.

Is it possible to do that?

```
def main():
    a = fun1()
    b = fun2()
    c = fun3()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I write pytest for this scenario? When I tried like this it didn't work.

```
test_def main():
a = myprogram.main()
    assert a is None
```

I wanted to achieve if main is being called or not but no other operations in main should invoke.

Is it possible to do so? If yes please suggest me a way. Else please let me know my mistake.

Comment: Just patch that functions. Then the Mocks will be called instead the internal functions. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html

Comment: @Igle I'm unable to proceed can you please explain with simple example

Comment: Were you able to proceed through this  ?